# How to increase resolution of 3D image in GRASS NVIZ

Tags: grass-gis, 3d, visualisation, nviz

I am trying to make 3D visualization of terrain data and orthophoto using GRASS NVIZ  via QGIS. I have been able to import both the DTM and the orthophoto in NVIZ window and successfully draped the image over DTM. But the resolution looks very poor. Is there any way to increase the resolution ? It seems like NVIZ GUI is not so user-friendly. For example, in Arcscene, there is a option to optimize the rendering that  can increase the resolution of the 3D draped image. Here is the screeshot from GRASS NVIZ:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your GRASS region/resolution is based on your DTM (which is low).

You should set it based on your orthophoto :

```
g.region rast=orthophotoLayername
```

Refresh your 3D viz.

By the way, could you edit your question adding what's is displayed by both `g.region -p rast=mnt_layer` and `g.region -p rast=orthophotoLayername`? It will be useful to know the resolution of your layers.

Comment: Hello Simo, thanks for your reply. My DTM has a resolution of 1.6 m whereas orthophoto has 0.1 m. I set region's resolution to taht of orthophoto with the command, "g.region nsres=0.1 ewres=0.1". Now if i run NVIZ, I got the following error, Current region rows: 40288, cols: 49184
ERROR: G_malloc: unable to allocate 3631132672 bytes of memory at gsds.c:575. Do I have to maek a subset of my data ? But I need to visualize an area with 10 km x 10 km. Thanks

Comment: GRASS is looking for 3.4 Gb of memory. It seems your machine has not enough RAM. You can define a smaller region, or crop it : http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Cropping_maps

Answer (score 2):

There are many parameters for the resolution of rasters in Nviz:

- the resolution(s) of the raster(s) (parameter **Res**)

  Type of Map:  raster
    ....
    Number of Categories: 0
    N: 175738.80821982    S:   9070.736   Res: 19.91493275
    E: 298336.77386818    W:  62265.161   Res: 19.91493275
    ....
- the resolution of the region (as Simo says)
- the parameters of resolution in Nviz **coarse**, when you move the image, and **fine**, static representation.

[image]

**- Fine= 1 means that the Nviz resolution is that previously fixed by `g.region` (current region resolution) and not the resolution of a specific raster**

- MNT seen with Fine= 1 or g.region  derived  from the MNT

[image]

#### The problem: what happens if you want to drape a raster with a different resolution on the MNT ?

If the current resolution is higher than the resolution of the raster used for topography, the raster is automatically resampled ( nearest neighbor algorithm) leading to a discontinuous surface with "steps".

- Result with the draped raster an g.region = MNT

[image]

- Result with the draped raster and g.region = raster

[image]

- MNT with g.region = raster

[image]

#### To solve the problem:

1) you can adjust the fine resolution of Nviz (ratio between the two resolutions):

[image][image][image]

2) but **if the only interest is to improve the 3D representation, the solution is to resample one of the rasters** (but you can no longer use it in other treatments, so use [g.copy](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/g.copy.html)) with:

- [r.resample.rst](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.resamp.rst.html): regularized spline with tension and smoothing

[image]

- or [r.resamp.interp](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.resamp.interp.html) nearest neighbor, bilinear and bicubic interpolation

[image]

Draping other raster on the MNT (other resolution):

[image]